# Why are my new tie rod ends or ball joints sticking?

Tags: dodge, steering

A mechanic replaced the ball joints and tie rod ends on my 1994 Dodge 1500 and now the steering sticks so badly that it's dangerous to drive. What could be the cause and solution?

Comment: Something I interfering with steering travel. Jack up the front end, put it on jacks stands, then have someone crank the steering back and forth, right to left. You should be able to tell where the binding is occurring.

Comment: I'd say that the most likely culprit would be in the ball joints. tie rods don't require using a press and if the mechanic wasn't careful he could of crushed the ball joint into the bushing. I'd suggest bringing the car back.

Comment: @Ben ... spot on. Agree completely.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the most likely culprit would be in the ball joints. Tie rods don't require using a press and if the mechanic wasn't careful he could of crushed the ball joint into the bushing. I'd suggest bringing the car back.